# Unskewing nav bar dropdown only HTML5/CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Testing out a navigation bar and right now I have each piece of it skewed -30 deg. When any given piece is clicked, its content drops down to display below what was clicked.

I'd like to have the part of the clicked piece that opens up to reveal the content be a normal rectangle but instead the parallelogram just gets bigger to hold the content inside. So ideally the part that was clicked would keep it's skews on top but open up with a rectangular bottom to hold its content.

Tried messing around with how the div's contain each other and moving around the

```
        transform: skewX(30deg);
     -o-transform: skewX(30deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(30deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(30deg);
```

but only seemed to make things worse, any help appreciated!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUwyj/

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ZUwyj/1/

Comment: This is more what I was looking for, but the header texts dont get straightened out for some reason? Looks like the .header CSS part isn't doing anything, looks the same when removed?

Comment: Think instead of calling on .header again have to just make another div inside the header one - seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/ZUwyj/2/

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add an active class to the nav with `skewX(0deg)`.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bDrT/4).

**EDIT**

Updated JsFiddle